# Parse String Data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm having trouble generating a regex to parse the following data, extracting the two decimal values so I can input them into 2 separate columns. What would be the ruby or rails helper code to do this?

Here is a visual representation of the table data:

```
| Percentage Range |
|------------------|
| 17 - 20.4%       |
| 7 - 20.4%        |
| 17 - 20.4%       |
| 25 - 30%         |
| 16.5 - 19.8%     |
| 25 - 30%         |
| 16.5 - 19.8%     |
| 25 - 30%         |
| 16.5 - 19.8%     |
-------------------
```

When I import, then iterate through the above table data, I would like to extract the decimal values and assign them to two variables. Here is the closest I can get it

```
@sample_data.each do |p|

  low_value  = p.percentage_range.gsub('regex goes here') #17 for ex
  high_value = p.percentage_range.gsub('regex goes here') #20.4 for example
end
```

Comment: That snippet in the top is a text block, correct?

Comment: @AnthonyE That's just a sample of the data from a table I'm importing. I'd like to extract it out into two columns when importing into my rails app

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your effort in solving this. What code did you write toward solving the problem? Why didn't it work? As is it looks like you want us to write the code for you, which isn't the Stack Overflow way. Please add the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan unfortunately that's not possible in this scenario.  I understand the ruby method .gsub, but know absolutely zero about regular expressions.  The only thing I could do is type a blank method to satisfy stack overflow guidelines for this question. dumb

Comment: It *IS* possible. What have you tried? If you haven't tried, why not? Asking a question on Stack Overflow isn't the first stop when learning, it's the last stop after searching and trying and trying and running out of ideas. Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. We want to help, but we want to know you've helped yourself and your evidence of effort is the clue. Failing to show effort will get questions closed quickly. "What would be the ruby or rails helper code to do this?" is off-topic because you're asking us to research for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp

```
\|\s*([\d+\.]+)\s*-\s*([\d+\.]+)%\s*\|
```

I tested it here http://rubular.com/r/r4RPDfqqqU

I think you can read data line by line and if you have matches save them other way it can be header or separated line ("--------------").

Comment: The sample data I gave above is a visual representation of table data I'm trying to parse.  the actual data in the field would be `17.4 - 20.4%`.  I need to extract and separate the two decimal values regardless of their size. My apologies for not being clearer lol

Comment: just remove two `\|` (at the start and at the end) from the regexp

Answer (score 0):

Regex are slippery little things, and the bigger they are, the more likely they are to get out of control.

I'd do something like this:

```
input = <<EOT
| Percentage Range |
|------------------|
| 17 - 20.4%       |
| 7 - 20.4%        |
EOT


input.lines[2 .. -1].map{ |l| l.scan(/[\d.]+/) }
# => [["17", "20.4"], ["7", "20.4"]]
```

The core of this is the regex `/[\d.]+/` in `scan`, which basically means: Find digits and decimal-points.

Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

```
input.lines
# => ["| Percentage Range |\n", "|------------------|\n", "| 17 - 20.4%       |\n", "| 7 - 20.4%        |\n"]
```

`lines` splits a string on its embedded line-ends, returning an array of lines.

```
input.lines[2 .. -1]
# => ["| 17 - 20.4%       |\n", "| 7 - 20.4%        |\n"]
```

That returns the lines we want.

You should be able to figure out the rest.

---

Looking at your code:

```
@sample_data.each do ||

  low_value  = p.percentage_range.gsub('regex goes here') #17 for ex
  high_value = p.percentage_range.gsub('regex goes here') #20.4 for example
end
```

There are several things wrong:

- `||` isn't necessary, nor does it help your code be more understandable.
- What is `p`?
- What is `percentage_range`?
- `gsub` is to do a global substitution, and is inappropriate here. Don't replace stuff when you want to match/find. There's a big difference in purpose and usually one won't substitute for the other.

If you don't want to use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan), which is the obvious go-to method for this:

> `scan(pattern)` → array

[...]

> Both forms iterate through str, matching the pattern (which may be a Regexp or a String). For each match, a result is generated and either added to the result array or passed to the block. If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, $&. If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

```
a = "cruel world"
a.scan(/\w+/)        #=> ["cruel", "world"]
a.scan(/.../)        #=> ["cru", "el ", "wor"]
a.scan(/(...)/)      #=> [["cru"], ["el "], ["wor"]]
a.scan(/(..)(..)/)   #=> [["cr", "ue"], ["l ", "wo"]]
```

then you could use other ways of grabbing the data:

```
low, high = '17 - 20.4%'.scan(/[\d.]+/)
# => ["17", "20.4"]

low, high = '17 - 20.4%'.match(/([\d.]+)\s+-\s+([\d.]+)/).captures
# => ["17", "20.4"]

low, high = '17 - 20.4%'.tr(' %', '').split('-')
# => ["17", "20.4"]
```

Notice that the pattern for `match` is a lot more complex and less readable. It could be somewhat simplified using variations such as:

```
low, high = '17 - 20.4%'.match(/([\d.]+).+?([\d.]+)%/).captures
# => ["17", "20.4"]
```

but `scan` remains more simple and to the point and uses a trivial pattern.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear on my question.  The table above is simply a visual representation of sample data in a database table.  The actual data in the field would be `17.4 - 20.4%`. I need to extract and separate the two decimal values into two variables. My apologies for not being clearer lol.  This question turned into a cluster.

Comment: It's really important to think out the question prior to asking, and to provide the information necessary. "[ask]" goes into this well, especially the links at the bottom of the page. The technique I showed will work in your new scenario just as well as the other. You need to figure out how to apply it.

Comment: If the data is truly in a table, then your question makes even less sense and is an XY problem, where you're asking about Y instead of X, which should have been "how do I extract data from a database" and is a core point in any [tutorial about Rails' Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: You shouldn't answer a question if you don't know the programming language the question is about.  In Rails the `@sample_data` is an array of hashes.  Each hash represents a table row. The `@sample_data. each do |p|` is the start of a `block`.  Think of it as for loop that iterates through each row.  `p.percentage_value` would access a single attribute in that row.  In this case that attribute is the string `17.3 - 19.5%` in the `Percentage Range` column.

Comment: I have a decent idea how Ruby and Rails work. You changed your code after I answered. The sample of your code in my answer is the original, and the revision history of your question shows you changed it from `do ||` to `do |p|`. It's not possible from your question to tell what `@sample_data` was; Rails or not, it wasn't clear and could have been an array or a hash or some iterable custom object instance. At that point `p.percentage_range` couldn't be determined either. Feel free to present this on Meta.StackOverflow if you feel your question was asked/presented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but the following handles tokenization and parsing for each row:

```
each_row.map do |row|
  value_pair = row.scan(/\d+.?\d+ - \d+\.?\d+/).map do |token|
    token.split(" - ").map(&:to_f)
  end

  # Unwrap
  value_pair = Array(value_pair)

  {
    highest: value_pair[0],
    lowest:  value_pair[1]
  }
end
```

P.S. Please try to be more specific in your prompt, had to rewrite this more than once as you changed your question.

Comment: A good clue that a question isn't well defined is to look at the number of comments immediately following the question. When I see more than two I carefully read the question and if there are answers with several comments then I'm sure there's a definition problem, and mark the question as that, and ask for clarification. It's better to not answer a poorly defined question as it doesn't benefit the site; conversely, answer well defined questions.